# Dropdown reset query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive made the following with lots of trial and error..... It works in a webpage but not as a jquerymobile. (The stopwatch button should change to 'Stop" when 'Start is pressed'. Also, the dropdown boxes don't clear if I re-select in the 1st choice dropdown. I'd also like the final dropdown to display automatically rather than 'selecting' the dropdown. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
           {
               document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").length = 0;
               document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select bottom time","");
               document.getElementById("subcategory").length = 0;
               switch (listindex)
               {
                   case "9" :
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("No Limit","");
                       break;

                   case "12" :
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select bottom time","");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("120","120-12");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("165","165-12");
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("195","195-12");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("225","225-12");
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("255","255-12");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[6]=new Option("330","330-12");
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[7]=new Option("390","390-12");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[8]=new Option("660","660-12");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[9]=new Option("Over 660","Over 660-12");
                       break;
                   case "15" :
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select bottom time","");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("75","75-15");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("105","105-15");
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("120","120-15");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("135","135-15");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("145","145-15");
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[6]=new Option("160","160-15");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[7]=new Option("170","170-15");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[8]=new Option("190","190-15");
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[9]=new Option("240","240-15");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[10]=new Option("360","360-15");
                       document.getElementById("subcategory").options[11]=new Option("450","450-15");
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[12]=new Option("Over 450","Over 450-15");
                       break;
                  
               }
               return true;
           }

           function dynamicdropdownone(listindex)
           {
               document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").length = 0;
               switch (listindex)
               {
                   case "120-12" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("No Stops required","");
                       break;
                   case "165-12" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("5min @ 3M","");
        break;
                   case "195-12" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("10min @ 3M","");
                       break;
                   case "225-12" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("15min @ 3M","")
                       break;
                   case "255-12" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("20min @ 3M","");
                      break;
       case "330-12" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("25min @ 3M","");
                       break;
                   case "390-12" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("30min @ 3M","");
                       break;
       case "660-12" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("35min @ 3M","");
                       break;
       case "Over 660-12" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("40min @ 3M","");
                       break;
        
       case "75-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("No Stops required","");
                       break;
                   case "105-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("5min @ 3M","");
        break;
                   case "120-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("10min @ 3M","");
                       break;
                   case "135-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("15min @ 3M","")
                       break;
                   case "145-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("20min @ 3M","");
                      break;
       case "160-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("25min @ 3M","");
                       break;
                   case "170-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("(5min @ 6M) -- (25min @ 3M)","");
                       break;
       case "190-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("(5min @ 6M) -- (30min @ 3M)","");
                       break;
       case "240-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("1(0min @ 6M) -- (40min @ 3M)","");
                       break;
       case "360-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("30min @ 6M -- 40min @ 3M","");
                       break;
                   case "450-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("35min @ 6M -- 40min @ 3M","");
                       break;
       case "Over 450-15" :
                       document.getElementById("sub_subcategory").options[0]=new Option("35min @ 6M -- 45min @ 3M","");
                       break;

       
                   default:
               }
               return true;
           }
      </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
 <div data-role="header">
  <h1>Divesupervisor</h1>
 </div>
    <div class="category_div" id="category_div">
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>Please select depth:
           <select name="category" class="required-entry" id="category" onChange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
             <option value="">Depth in meters</option>
             <option value="9">9</option>
             <option value="12">12</option>
             <option value="15">15</option>
         
           </select>
         </p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
       <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
         <p>Please select bottom time:
           <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
               document.write('<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdownone(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"><option value="">Time in minutes</option></select>')
           </script>
           <noscript>
               <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >
                 <option value="">Time in minutes</option>
               </select>
           </noscript>
         </p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
       </div>
       <div class="sub_subcategory_div" id="sub_subcategory_div">Decompression stops:
         <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
               document.write('<select name="sub_subcategory" onchange="javascript: urlRedirectTo(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" id="sub_subcategory"><option value="">Stops required</option></select>')
           </script>
           <noscript>
               <select name="sub_subcategory" id="sub_subcategory" >
                   <option value="">Required stops</option>
               </select>
         </noscript>
         
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var sec = -1;
var min = 0;
var hour = 0;
function stopwatch(text) {
   sec++;
  if (sec == 60) {
   sec = 0;
   min = min + 1; }
  else {
   min = min; }
  if (min == 60) {
   min = 0; 
   hour += 1; }

if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }
   document.clock.stwa.value = ((hour<=9) ? "0"+hour : hour) + " : " + ((min<=9) ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec;

  if (text == "Start") { document.clock.theButton.value = "Stop "; }
  if (text == "Stop ") { document.clock.theButton.value = "Start"; }

  if (document.clock.theButton.value == "Start") {
   window.clearTimeout(SD);
   sec=sec-1;
   return true; }
SD=window.setTimeout("stopwatch();", 1000);
}

function resetIt() {
  sec = -1;
  min = 0;
  hour = 0;
  if (document.clock.theButton.value == "Stop ") {
  document.clock.theButton.value = "Start"; }
  window.clearTimeout(SD);
 }

           </script>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#0000FF" vlink="#0000FF" alink="#FF0000">
</div>
<tr valign="top">
  <td width="10%" bgcolor="#c5c3c4" align="left"><br /></td><td><p><table align="center" width="80%" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
     <td align="center">
       <form name="clock"><br />
       <input type="text" size="12" name="stwa" /><br />
       <input type="button" name="theButton" onClick="stopwatch(this.value);" value="Start" />
       <input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="resetIt();reset();" />
       </form>
     </td>
  </tr>     
</table>
</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td colspan="2"><br /><div align="center">


</div></body></html>
 
 <div data-role="footer">
  <h4>----</h4>
 </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Know that this is NOT (yet) an answer (which I can delete later, if necessary), but I could not put any of this detail/information in a regular comment to the original post...

=====

What device(s) are you using? The aspects that you mentioned seem to be working OK for me on a Nexus 6P.

However, to use your code I had to match the jquery sources to what I have, which is newer, and I'm **NOT** saying that you need to update those files.

Know that there are some tag-placement (and other) complaints, that may cause layout and/or other issues with older phone/tablet devices.

[image: warning list]

You should be able to easily match those line numbers in your editor. Make sure that the `<!DOCTYPE html>` is on the first line. I did not add or remove any lines, but only copy/pasted your code. You have two closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags near the bottom. Know that with the `<script>` tags that attribute `language` is no longer needed, and the attribute `type` is optional with HTML5.

Here's a few screenshots running on my phone: (not in any particular order)

[image: phone screenshots]

I'll stop here, for now. Feel free to ask any questions if needed.

Oh, on a side note ... if it might help de-clutter the HTML for you, move all of your javascript code into a separate file, and then reference that file with a script tag in a similar manner as the jquery files by using the `src` attribute. You can leave it as-is for now if you'd like, as this is only a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and taking time to look at this for me. I am using 'Dreamweaver' and trying it on a Jquery mobile template. It all works fine in a webpage, but not on the mobile template, causing the issues mentioned. I'm very limited in my coding ability- hence dreamweaver!! Thanks for the de-clutter advice. That sounds like another project, but certainly something to consider.......when I work out how!!